# "It is where something happens." VS "It is there that something happens."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

This is from a video about how planets and stars are born and how life might have started.

**.....and it's these dense clouds that are of interest to ALMA, because it's there that planets and stars begin to form.** [Galaxies and stars and planets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ9w-xFAq2U) (See:22:38-22:43)

In terms of structure, I would probably not be able to form such a good structure as a non-native speaker. The closest I would say probably would be:

**"....because it is where planets and stars begin to form."**

However, when I compare my sentence to the original one, the original one sounds better, although there seems to be no difference in meaning. I am not quite sure why the first one sounds better.

Is it simply because it is more idiomatic to say it that way or is anything wrong with my structure **"It is where something happens."** instead of **"It is there that something happens."**

Comment: I don't understand how you can simultaneously say *you* wouldn't be able to generate the actual phrasing as cited, yet you claim to be able to somehow "sense" that it's better than your alternative. The truth is they're both ***perfectly good*** for the context, and there's no real point in trying to decide which is "best" or "more idiomatic". If such a blanket judgement *were* possible, don't you think all Anglophones would have switched to the "better" version generations ago?

Comment: **There** means **in these dense clouds**. The sentence doesn't work so well with _where_ - you would have to say **because they** (the clouds) **are where planets begin to form.**

Comment: @KateBunting: Each to their own. I don't have a problem with just repeating ***it's*** in the exact context - syntax notwithstanding, my "semantic" perspective is if it's good enough for ***it's** these dense clouds...,* it's good enough to refer to exactly the same thing using exactly the same pronoun for it's ***where*** it's at!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't worry too much about it. This is about tone. The constructions "It is there that X happens" and "This is where X happens" (or similar) are pretty much equivalent in meaning. And I wouldn't recommend using the "it is there that" construction in informal contexts, and "this is where" wouldn't be bad even in formal contexts.

The construction you found gives a somewhat lofty tone, somewhat poetical. It would sound odd in casual conversation, but appropriate in speechmaking (or science/anthropology documentary voiceovers). To use this in everyday speech with friends would make you sound like an orator or documentary narrator. When in doubt, I would choose a simpler construction like the one you suggested.